# Cocos2d-x admob Integration

Tags: android, admob, cocos2d-x

Is there any good link from where I can integrate cocos2d-x admob in my app.
My Activity is extending CCLayer.

How can I approach integrating admob in that File.
Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may choose Plugin-x for your project.Click [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Plugin-X) :)

Answer (score 1):

http://rastergrid.com/blog/2013/03/admob-extension-for-cocos2d-x-android/

Here is an excellent tutorial to integrate admob in cocos2D-x (Android) step by step.
I had followed that tutorial and that works!

On iOS it will be very easy for you to intergrate admob because c++ and object-c can work together. What you need to do is make a bridge between c++ and admob iOS SDK code which is written in object-c

In fact I don't think that there would be a perfect cross-platform 3rd-party SDK integration solution. You may need to do separate implemention on each platform.

Comment: Hi ThankCreate, This is not working for me.
I have done all the steps but can't make it work.

If I have the library, i mean .so file already, and I dont want to comile CCAdView.h and CCAdView.cpp.
Will copy pasting that library work??